Как вывести в файл значение списка
Есть код, он создаёт список 23x13 значений. Надо данные значения вывести в файл.
Вот сам код:
from math import sqrt 
from random import randint

n = 1
m = 6
grid = [[randint(n, m) for j in range(23)] for i in range(13)]
f = open('Values_​​for_the_passage_map.txt', 'w')

# Данная строчка должна вписывать список grid в файл.

f.close()

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать? На форумах обычно либо обычный текст выводят, либо совсем другое строение кода с меньшим значением списка, и через цикл.

Переменная grid у вас типа list, а в файл можно записывать данные типа str.
То есть, что бы сменить тип данных:
f.write(str(grid)) # не '', а str делает весь список строкой

Но в вашем случае идеальным решением будет перебрать весь список и красиво с отступами внести данные в файл:
for g in grid:
    f.write(str(g) + '\n')


Ну тогда уже стоит показать, как каждую строчку сформировать, чтобы колонки ровные были.

MBo, колонки и так ровные, числа которые должны будут задавать n и m будут опрпедляться числами от 1 до 20(это часть кода, так как сказали, что слишком легкое задание дал студентам, надо хотя бы добавить вариант и пускай будет вывод в файл и потом другой программой(основной) чтение из него.
Хм, только сейчас задумался, что при вариантах до 10, а также 20 - будет плахая выборка, надо пересмотерть формирование этих переменных.
Спасибо вам за данную возможность увидеть данные просчет.

Можно с помощью модуля json:
...
import json
...

И далее используем функцию json.dump:
...
f = open('Values_​​for_the_passage_map.txt', 'w')
json.dump(grid, f)  # <--
f.close()

Подробнее про json.dump в документации.
